# How to convert a token span into a character span with Spacy

Tags: python, spacy

How do I get the character span in the original string from a token level span in a Spacy doc?

```
N = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
text = 'Joe Biden is president of the US'
doc = N(text)
e = doc.ents[0]

# ??? get the character span, [0:9] in this case, from the token span (e.start==0, e.end==2) for a named entity
# so that text[ <<character-span>> ] == e.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Span object has start_char and end_char attributes. (https://spacy.io/api/span/#section-attributes)

```
text[e.start_char:e.end_char]
# output : 'Joe Biden'
```